# cx_freeze creates exe that requests admin rights

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze

I am using cx_freeze 4.3.3 for python 3.3. It creates an exe file, but out of sudden, the created file asks for admin rights. This never happened before. 
And I need it to create exe files that do not request admin rights. 
Is there a reason why it is doing that? Or is there a way to set it up so the file won't request admin rights?

Here's the setup.py code:

```
import sys

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable



base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name = "QueueUpdate",
    version = "1.6",
    description = "Tracker for CRAP. Internally, our hamsters work very\
    hard to keep track of your time. Be grateful and find a way to feed them.",
    executables = [Executable("queueupdate2.py", base = base)]
)
```

Thank you